# How to run Dragnn framework (TensorFlow)?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, syntaxnet

I have been dealing with some NLP tools (TINT, UDPIPE,Syntaxnet..). I was able to run the basic Syntaxnet NLP framework from commandline, but I really can't understand how to run Dragnn.
I just want a complete .conll format given a plain text (like I do with Syntaxnet)!

Can anyone give me some help and hints?
Unfortunately the documentation is really blurry